# MS SQL query with wildcard and select dont work... but why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard, date-format

I'm new in SQL and I am trying to debug this:

This works:

```sql
(SELECT TRY_PARSE((SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, '12.02.2021')) AS DATE USING 'en-gb'))
```

This works too:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees 
WHERE BirthDay LIKE (SELECT TRY_PARSE((SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, '2.12.1989')) AS DATE USING 'en-gb'))
```

This works too:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Employees 
WHERE BirthDay LIKE '%2%'
```

BUT this doesn't work:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Employees
WHERE BirthDay LIKE '%(SELECT TRY_PARSE((SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, '2')) AS DATE USING 'en-gb'))%'
```

Why? I write something impossible or do I mistake somewhere?
The idea is that I read from desktop app date (input from user) in EU format, convert it in US format and search in database with only day or only year or only month (not full date) for matches.

Example: I need all birthdays with month 12, I type 12, and search in database for matches.

Output: 20.12.2000, 11.12.1945, 1.12.1977 ...

---

EDIT:
Thx for help, but this not work :(

i find the right format:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees
WHERE BirthDay LIKE '%' + (SELECT TRY_PARSE((SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, '1989')) AS DATE USING 'en-gb')) + '%'
```

But when i searching for solution i read more about "TRY_PARSE" and this return full date, if i input only day or only year, the function return "null" cuz dont have full date to read. Im not sure but for now i think this is my mistake...

Comment: A date does not have a format. `TRY_PARSE` returns a date, not a string representation of a date, so it's not in a us format, it's without any format. To do partial lookups on such date, use `where month(BirthDay) = 12`, at which point you don't even want to pass the user input (`12`) as a date.

Answer (score 1):

Because if you read the manual you will see that LIKE does compare the left side to the right side, which is a string.

Not SQL Code, a STRING.

It is not interpreted in any way outside what is documented for strings with wildcards.

So, basically you do look for

Birthday

BEING LIKE THE FOLLOWING STRING:

> %(SELECT TRY_PARSE((SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, '2')) AS DATE USING 'en-gb'))%

It is not doing any interpretation on that and obviously none of your birthdays are that particular SQL statement.